# How to make better use of ng-repeat and directives in angular.js app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've having a few issues with my first angular.js project, It's working perfectly fine but I've had to input all my values 1 by 1 which is very time consuming and bad code practice but on the brightside has drilled some basic angular into my head. I've been trying for days to put my html code into directive or using ng-repeat to try and display the specific type of measurement and work out the equations without having VERY LONG directives full of if statements. I'm certain theres a workaround for this I just need some guidance to finding it. Many thanks for the help, the project link can be found below, please note at the time or writing this I hadn't inputted the calculations for mass.

[Codepen Measurement Calculator Project](http://codepen.io/ajduff14/pen/yyvvXG?editors=001)

heres a small snippet of my repetitive code that I'm wanting to shorten somehow...

```
      <input type="text"  ng-model="MetersS" ng-keyup="Speed.Convert('MetersS',MetersS)">
      <label>{{type.measurement[2].in[3]}}</label>
      <input type="text"  ng-model="Kmh" ng-keyup="Speed.Convert('Kmh',Kmh)">
      <label>{{type.measurement[2].in[4]}}</label>
      <input type="text"  ng-model="Knot" ng-keyup="Speed.Convert('Knot',Knot)">
```

Regards,

Adam

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for the code review site.

Comment: If this is posted to Code Review, please provide more of your code. Otherwise it can be considered "example code", which is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you guys mean? Am I missing out on something here? I don't use stackoverflow very often at all by the way!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started on your way. There are of course many different ways to set things up, but this should give you the idea.
In your app you can setup some objects:

```
  $scope.thevals = ['meters','kms'];

  $scope.values = {
    meters:{value:undefined,conv:'meters'},
    kms:{value:undefined,conv:'km'}

  };
```

And then use it in a repeat like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="obj in thevals">
    {{obj}}
    <input type="text"  ng-model="values[obj].value" ng-keyup="Speed.Convert(values[obj].conv)">
  </div>
```

Comment: Cheers for this, I think I need to have a look deeper into the use of $scope to fully understand what your doing first. I've gone for this .this object call, it looks something along the lines of what I was attempting though/